# Java default Interface Methods

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default-method

Here is my simple code from a Java Tutorial.

```
public interface AnimalIntf {

    default public String identifyMyself(){
        return "I am an animal.";
    }

}
```

I get an error: illegal start of type interface methods cannot have body. 
The method is default and the default keyword is used at the beginning of the method signature. 
Could you please explain to me what is wrong?

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom, JDK 1.6

Comment: You need JDK 8 to use default methods.

Comment: Surprisingly, you seem to be the first person to ask this question (or maybe the SO search is so useless it can't find the duplicate).

Comment: It would be interesting to know what kind of tutorial is was. Does it really introduce Java 8 features to the audience failing to tell that it aims at Java 8?

Comment: By the way `Java 6` aka `JDK 1.6` has it’s official “end of life” reached at [Feb 2013](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html#Java6-end-public-updates). You shouldn’t start learning Java with an outdated version.

Comment: @Yuliana I think folks here have adequately answered your question.  If you agree, please "Accept" an answer (doesn't have to be mine).

Comment: @Holger, It is Oracle's Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/

Comment: @JustinKSU, you are right, thanks, didn't know about the 'accept'

Comment: Well, Oracle’s tutorial says it [on the start page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/): “*The Java Tutorials primarily describe features in Java SE 8. For best results, [download JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)*”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default interface methods were introduced in Java 8, so you need a JDK that supports Java 8 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You must use Java 8 or above to have default implementations in interfaces.  Instead you could use an abstract class.  But even then, you wouldn't use the `default` keyword.

Comment: Oh, you meant if you're using an abstract class instead, you don't use `default` there.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I have found this, the link could be helpful while determining which one to use, an interface or an abstract class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

Strange things are happening... 
After the JDK update to version 8 both on computer and in IDE settings, the code compiles OK, but the IDE still marks the line

```
default public String identifyMyself(){
```

as error. And there were still errors while trying to use the interface, asking to override the default method in the class that implements the interface.

```
public class Dragon implements Animal{    
}
```

2 hours later I got tired of trying to fix my NetBeans v.6.9.1 and downloaded NetBeans v8.0.1. 
Now I am fine :)